# Drupal - Core Search Module Error

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Search module was previously working before I'm not sure what.

Every time I search for a keyword (verified that it's in the article) the search returns:

You must include at least one positive keyword with 3 characters or more.

Along with No Search Results found.

I've read that some times a module can cause a conflict but I have disabled module by module, running update and cron each time.  On the search settings, there are no nodes waiting to be indexed, and I have no third party search module installed.  Any ideas :) ?

Comment: So what was the term you were trying to search for ?

Comment: Any term that are tags in the different nodes.  No matter what I search for it returns no results and that error message.  It is very frustrating ><

Comment: Have you tried to reindex your search? Drush can help here.

Comment: Yep, tried reindexing multiple times already.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Looks like an open thread for the Drupal people: https://drupal.org/node/876026 and https://drupal.org/node/177163

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this multiple times and each time it has been as a result of switching PHP mode from php-fast-cgi to php-fpm. The quick/interim solution is to change the PHP mode and re-index the content in Drupal.

Update 2014/6/20:
Updating Drupal core and some modules (clientside_validation, ctools, context) to match enabled the site to fun on PHP 5.3 fpm without issues. Just the core update allowed search to work again, but we updated the modules because a number of them were using PHP structures that are obsolete as of 5.3 fpm